# Euler-Maclaurin summation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I want to compute asymptotic approximations to  partial sum of  [harmonic series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicSeries.html) in *Mathematica*, using [Euler-Maclaurin](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MaclaurinIntegrationFormulas.html) summation formula.

```
f[x_] := 1/x

em[n_] := Integrate[f[x], {x, 1, n}]
   + (f[1] + f[n])/2
   + Sum[BernoulliB[2k]/(2k)! ((D[ f[x], {x, 2 k - 1}] /. x -> n)
   - D[f[x], {x, 2 k - 1}] /. x -> 1), {k, 1, Infinity}]

em[k] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

`FullSimplify` does not work..

How to simplify this expression?   Where is a $\gamma$?

I try it in *Maple*:

[image]

How to do something like this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: I think the missing $\gamma$ comes from the 'remainder' term of the Euler-Maclaurin formula.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest adding option `GenerateConditions->False` to `Integrate` to speed up the integration.  Then, instead of `D`, use `Derivative`.  Then, to generate a `SeriesData` apply `Series`:

```
f[x_] := 1/x;
max = 4;

em[n_Symbol] := 
 Series[Integrate[f[x], {x, 1, n}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False] + (f[1] + f[n])/2 + 
  Sum[BernoulliB[2 k]/(2 k)! (Derivative[2 k - 1][f][n] - 
    Derivative[2 k - 1][f][1]), {k, 1, max+3}], {n, Infinity, max}]
```

Then

```
em[n]
```

> [image]

Note: if you do `em[k]`, you get conflict of local variables.

Comment: I get 2897/5040 for max=1, but for max=4 (in example) I get 51621/80080

Comment: In addition, for max=10 I get 8268803161823011/160626866400, these terms does not converge to (correct) EulerGamma. This program need a correction.

Comment: Had you a chance to fix this interesting piece of code ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [`AsymptoticSum`](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/asymptotics/compute-a-riemann-sum-approximation-asymptoticsum.html),

```
In[1]:= AsymptoticSum[1/k, {k, 1, n}, n \[Rule] Infinity, SeriesTermGoal \[Rule] 7]

                       1        1        1      1
Out[1]= EulerGamma - ------ + ------ - ----- + --- + Log[n]
                          6        4       2   2 n
                     252 n    120 n    12 n
```

Alternatively,

```
In[2]:= Series[Unevaluated[Sum[1/k, {k, 1, n}]], {n, Infinity, 7}]

                                 1      1       1        1          -8
Out[2]= (EulerGamma + Log[n]) + --- - ----- + ------ - ------ + O[n]
                                2 n       2        4        6
                                      12 n    120 n    252 n
```

Both of them give the same result as Maple's `eulermac(1/k, k = 1 .. n, 5);`.